# Bootstrap breadcrumb styling with schema data

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to bootstrap and trying to style the breadcrumb. I tried this and it gives me the proper inline layout I want.

```
    <div class="BreadCrumbs">
          <a href="www.yahoo.com" >Yahoo</a>
          <span class="divider" > &gt; </span>
          <a href="www.example.com" >Example</a>
          <span class="divider" > &gt; </span> <a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
        </div>
```

But I want to add schema data and still maintain the proper styling. So I tried this but all the links are in different lines. How do I get them to be inline in one single line?

```
<div class = "BreadCrumbs" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
  <a href="www.yahoo.com" itemprop="url">
    <span itemprop="title">Yahoo</span>
  </a> ›
</div>  
<div class = "BreadCrumbs" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
  <a href="www.example.com" itemprop="url">
    <span itemprop="title">Example</span>
  </a> ›
</div>  
<div class = "BreadCrumbs" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
  <a href="www.google.com" itemprop="url">
    <span itemprop="title">Google</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: By default `<div>` is a block element so you need to style it from the css by using `display: inline-block` or by using `float:left` > if you use float don't forget to clear it afterwards

Comment: CSS is case sensitive. Since you're using `Breadcrumbs` instead of `breadcrumbs` it isn't loading the class properly. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/47vo4qzu/)

Comment: Also you need to switch from using `div` to an `ol` as `breadcrumbs` was designed for a list.

Answer (score 0):

From Google: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumbs

Use a list and then style the li elements inline

```
.breadcrumbs li {
     display: inline;
}

<div class="breadcrumbs"> 
<ol itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
  <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope
      itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
    <a itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing"
       itemprop="item" href="https://example.com/books">
        <span itemprop="name">Books</span>
        <img itemprop="image" src="http://example.com/images/icon-bookicon.png" alt="Books"/></a>
    <meta itemprop="position" content="1" />
  </li>
  ›
  <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope
      itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
    <a itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing"
       itemprop="item" href="https://example.com/books/sciencefiction">
      <span itemprop="name">Science Fiction</span>
      <img itemprop="image" src="http://example.com/images/icon-science-fiction.png" alt="Genre: Science Fiction"/></a>
    <meta itemprop="position" content="2" />
  </li>
  ›
  <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope
      itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
    <a itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing"
       itemprop="item" href="https://example.com/books/sciencefiction/ancillaryjustice">
      <span itemprop="name">Ancillary Justice</span>
      <img itemprop="image" src="http://example.com/images/cover-ancillary-justice.png" alt="Ancillary Justice"/></a>
    <meta itemprop="position" content="3" />
  </li>
</ol>
</div>
```